# How best to find an element in nested lists?

Tags: functional-programming, stream, kotlin

Kotlin provides some usingful extension functions allow stream-like programming.

For example, if I look for an element in a list I can use `find`:

```
return list.find { n -> n>4 && n<6 }
```

But when I have a have nested lists this seems not practical for me. I have tu use `forEach` then -- luckyly I can return from an inner Lambda with Kotlin:

```
private fun findUsingForEach(data: List<List<Int>>, pred : (Int) -> Boolean) : Optional<Int> {
    data.forEach { list ->
        list.forEach { n ->
            if( pred(n) ) return Optional.of(n)
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty()
}
```

It seems fo me that `forEach` is not the right tool for that. Is there a more functional way to du this? `filter` comes to mind, but the nesting causes problems.

That follwing is the test I use for the function abouve:

```
@Test
open fun findTest() {
    val data = listOf( listOf(1,2,3), listOf(3,4,5,6), listOf(), listOf(6,7,8) )
    val e = findUsingForEach( data, { n -> n>4 && n < 6 } )
    assertEquals(5, e.get())
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could [`flatten`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flatten.html) the list:

> `fun <T> Iterable<Iterable<T>>.flatten(): List<T>` ([source](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.0/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Iterables.kt#L77))
>
> Returns a single list of all elements from all collections in the given collection.

```
val data = listOf(listOf(1, 2, 3), listOf(3, 4, 5, 6), listOf(), listOf(6, 7, 8))
data.flatten().find { n -> n > 4 && n < 6 }
```

This will return a single list with the elements of the sublists in order. Then you can use `find` as usual.

In your example,

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {}, {6, 7, 8}}
```

becomes

```
{1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8}
```

and the result of `find` on this list is `5`.

However, this will create a new list. Take a look at the source of `flatten`:

```
/**
 * Returns a single list of all elements from all collections in the given collection.
 */
public fun <T> Iterable<Iterable<T>>.flatten(): List<T> {
    val result = ArrayList<T>()
    for (element in this) {
        result.addAll(element)
    }
    return result
}
```

If you want to save memory, create a [`Sequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/index.html) from your list first:

```
data.asSequence()
```

and then perform your operations on this sequence:

```
data.asSequence().flatten().find { n -> n > 4 && n < 6 }
```

---

Side note: your predicate, `n > 4 && n < 6`, is simply equivalent to `n == 5`.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to reduce codes and you don't care much about efficiency, try this.

```
list.flatten().find { your pred here }
```

Or

```
list.flatMap { it }.find { your pred }
```

Or create a useful utility which doesn't create new lists (faster/lower memory taken):

```
inline fun <T> Iterable<Iterable<T>>.forEachEach(f: (T) -> Unit) =
    forEach { it.forEach(f) }
```